# How to change bindingPropertyName on @Output() programmatically

Tags: angular, polymer

i need to change bindingPropertyName on one @Output() programmatically.

I use one directive for having two way binding between property in one polymer 2.0 component (with reflectToAttribute set to true) and my app in Angular 5.

Code:

```js
@Directive({
  selector: "[bindPolymer]"
})
export class BindPolymerDirective {

  @Output("valueChange") change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener("value-changed", ["$event.target.value"]) onInputChange(value) {
    if (value) {
      this.change.emit(value);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<polymer-input [(value)]="user" bindPolymer></polymer-input>
```

In this case the property who needed two way binding is value, so it work like a charm. But in other case he could be different.

Anyone could tell me how to achieve this ? Or maybe give me an other way to solve the problem ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, objects are references.

So simply doing

```
@Output("valueChange") change: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
@Output("valueChangeBis") changeBis = this.change;
```

Should do the trick

Comment: How to implement this inside a directive ?

Comment: Just like I wrote it !

Comment: @JoffreyHernandez [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oynxvf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) should show you how it's done.

Comment: My polymer librairie has something like 30 properties with reflectToAttribute set to true, this will mean i have to implement 30 @Output() inside this directive? He should have another way to achieve this...

Comment: I can't tell you, I'm not using Polymer. With more code and a [mcve] I might be able to tell you, but right know all I can tell you is that you need to explicitly declare the outputs of your directive.